# Pear::Image_Barcode output in CakePHP Controller

Tags: cakephp, pear

I want to output a barcode generated with PEAR::Image_Barcode in a CakePHP Controller:

```
public function gen_bc($bc_text = null)
{
    $this->autoRender = false;
    require_once("Image/Barcode.php");
    $bc = new Image_Barcode;
    $bc->draw($bc_text, "Code39", "jpg");
    exit();
}
```

But i get no output @ all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture your output. Use ob_start(). Otherwise, you will only have the barcode image in your screen.

```
require_once('Image/Barcode.php');

public function gen_bc($bc_text){
    ob_start();
    $img = Image_Barcode::draw( $bc_text ,'code128', 'png', false);
    $cif_data = ob_get_contents ();
    ob_end_clean();
}
```

If you get an error, try to ommit the errors:

```
require_once('Image/Barcode.php');

error_reporting(0);

public function gen_bc($bc_text){
    ob_start();
    $img = Image_Barcode::draw( $bc_text ,'code128', 'png', false);
    $cif_data = ob_get_contents ();
    ob_end_clean();
}
```